# mvc url route not being routed properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a bit of difficulty creating a new route for my MVC 4 application and the route, at least to me, seems to make sense however when trying to actually use the rewritten url it results in a 404.

What I'm trying to do is completely rewrite the url so that it is clearer to the user, so for example I want to have the following:

```
http://localhost/Product/Add
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost/admin/addproduct
```

My route looks as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("AddProduct", "Product/Add", new { controller = "Admin", action = "AddProduct" });
```

What is it that I've done wrong that would cause the routing engine to not route the url correctly?

Comment: Suggestion: Make an "admin" **Area** and have a Product Controller with an Add Action.. Thereby making the URL `/admin/Product/Add`.

Comment: Are you generating URL using `Url.RouteUrl`?

Comment: I suppose your route is located below default route "{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: Simon, that's ultimately one of the things that I want to avoid is creating an unnessecary controller. Ultimately what I want to achieve is to hide the controller from the user.

Comment: Provide complete `routes.MapRoute` list

Comment: People are guessing here, @codejam can you elaborate more on your situation. Though `Admin` seems to be, highly, an area is it really? Is it a controller? For us to be able to suggest properly, can you give more example of your controllers and methods and the routing you would like to achieve.

Comment: @dima You're exactly right and now I feel like a compete tool for forgetting that, that route is always supposed to be last.